# Can the temperature of the extremely early universe be negative? If so, does it have any measurable consequences?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang

We know at the Big Bang the universe is extremely hot. We also know that what is hotter than infinite temperature is negative temperature, provided that the system has an upper bound for energy, or equivalently the number of micro-states has an upper bound for any of its micro-canonical ensemble.

Given that we do not have a UV complete theory-of-everything, how do we know the universe did not once have a negative temperature? If indeed we can not rule it out, is it possible to detect its relics?

Comment: Lots of potentially useful discussion in [this thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11472.pdf).

Comment: I do not understand why the close votes. It is a well-defined question within the realm of modern physics.

Comment: Thanks @Chemomechanics for the reference.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, you should search Google Scholar for `"early universe" "negative temperature"` or similar terms to make sure you're not missing previous work. That thesis was the 6th hit on the list. (I agree that the topic is one of mainstream physics.)

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yup, I only searched the stack exchange.

Comment: How does this work? I would think that the early universe is an unbounded system, which presumably can't have negative temperature, since the density of states (as a function of energy) never dips back down because there are infinitely many states? Also, does negative temperature have any meaning/implications beyond  the idea that adding energy to the system lowers its entropy?

Comment: @justaphase We don't know if the universe has finite or infinite degrees of freedom. At the very least, we would need to know what the universe looks like at Planck scale.

Comment: @pathintegral I also don't know what you mean by "negative temperature is hotter than infinite temperature" but that sounds wrong. Negative temperature is meaningless except for one statement: that adding energy decreases entropy. Otherwise, the temperature corresponds to $|T|$. The sign is meaningless apart from dictating how entropy changes with energy (but the universe is a closed system so you can't add energy to it anyway). I guess it's possible that the early universe had bounded energy though.

Comment: @justaphase negative temp is well-defined in many textbooks. See e.g., page 12 of the lecture notes here https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html.

Comment: @pathintegral I know exactly what it is. But even Tong's excellent notes don't actually give a physical meaning to being "hotter than ∞ temp". The ONLY thing that negative temperature means is the thing he says about microstates versus energy. But who cares about that lol. I'm saying think of $T$ as $|T|$ and the sign just tells you about $\partial S / \partial E$. I would think that $T$ and $-T$ should be equally "hot", only entropy vs. energy slope is different. Unless someone has done an experiment showing that this sign matters.

Comment: @justaphase Tong didn't explain "hotter than infinity", but it's straightforward to see why. If you put an object with $T_1>0$ and with another one with $T_2<0$, energy actually flows from the negative-$T$ one to the positive-$T$ one to maximize entropy! This is precisely what "hotter than any positive $T$" means -- you don't want touch a negative-$T$ object because you'll get burnt. For details, see e.g., the equation below 1.8 in Tong. If $T_1>0,T_2<0$, then $\delta E_1>0$.

Comment: @pathintegral thanks for clarifying! I guess I had forgotten my thermodynamics! So I guess where we're at is the following: we can allow that a sufficiently early universe did not have an infinite number of microstates, meaning there could be a consequence to negative temp. But what is that consequence? I guess one point to make is that the universe isn't coupled to a bath...it doesn't have a temperature on the whole...but subsystems thereof do! So perhaps we could ask whether subsystems could've had negative temperature, and what that would imply? Otherwise, Idk if there *are* consequences?